# Show array group by "nat" key in table

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array from PDO result...

```
[AF] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 239
                            [nat] => AF
                            [entrydate] => 2013-08-27

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 240
                            [nat] => AF
                            [entrydate] => 2013-08-27

                        )

                )

        )
[AB] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 239
                            [nat] => AB
                            [entrydate] => 2013-08-27

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 240
                            [nat] => AB
                            [entrydate] => 2013-08-27

                        )

                )

        )
[AC] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 239
                            [nat] => AC
                            [entrydate] => 2013-08-27

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 240
                            [nat] => AC
                            [entrydate] => 2013-08-27

                        )

                )

        )
```

I want to produce a table like this...

```
  nat   key   Date
  AF    239   2013-08-27
        240   2013-08-27
  AB    239   2013-08-27
        240   2013-08-27
  AC    239   2013-08-27
        240   2013-08-27
```

the problem is when i need to get the above result in this code, not working some help...

```
    <tr>
        <th><?= _('nat')?></th>
        <th><?= _('key')?></th> 
        <th><?= _('Date')?></th> 
    </tr> 

    <?php 

        foreach($array as $ent) {

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$ent[0]['nat']?></td>
            <td><?=$ent[0]['key']?></td>
            <td><?=$ent[0]['entrydate']?></td>

        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use two loops to iterate through this (first you have to iterate through the main items, and then you have to iterate through their sub items.) You can keep a `$first` variable that describes whether it's the first time we go into the subitems for this NAT value, and hence only print the NAT value once:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($pdoResult as $natResult) {
            $first = true;

            foreach ($natResult['items'] as $natItem) {
                $natKey = ($first ? $natItem['nat'] : '');

                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $natKey ?></td>
                        <td><?= $natItem['key'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $natItem['entrydate'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php

                $first = false;
            }
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That is really helpful and explanatory answer, you have given. Thanks Boss!

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested array so you'll need nested loops:

```
foreach($array as $ent){
    foreach($ent['items'] as $item){
        echo $item['nat'] . " - " . $item['key'] . " - " . $item['entrydate'];
    }
}
```